# If a LP has multiple optimal solutions, does it have multiple optimal basic solutions?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I can not answer the following question:

> Consider an LP $P$ of the form $\{\max c^Tx \text{$\quad$ s.t. $\quad$ } Ax = b, x \ge 0 \}$, where $A$ has rank $m$. If $P$ has multiple optimal solutiosn then there are at least two optimal basic solutions.

I suspect that this is false, but I can not find a counter example. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Let $c$, $A$, and $b$ all be zero matrices of the corresponding size.

I will leave the task of finding  all the solutions and all the basic solutions to you.